# How can I remove spaces only from specific position using batch script

Tags: batch

I have an entry as below in my input file (input.txt)  :

```
mcolWarrant|||||||||        0||Forwarded||
mcolWarrant|||||||||        0||Forwarded||
mcolWarrant|||||||||        0||Forwarded||
mcolWarrant|AW000015|||||0A009919|388|MILTON KEYNES|     7000||
```

I just want to remove the trialing spaces before `"0" (        0)` and before `"7000"(     7000)`. How can I do so using batch scripting?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very imprecise, so my answer assumes the following:

- You are using Windows
- Each line of your file contains columns delimited by `|`
- You want to remove leading spaces from all columns
- You want to use a Windows batch script

Modifying files using pure batch scripting can be very difficult. Often times there are simple "solutions" that fail when confronted with common situations. There are almost always work-arounds, but the resulting batch scipt often becomes complicated and slow.

But there is a [powerful hybrid JScript/batch utility called REPL.BAT](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16735079/1012053) that can easily solve a great many text processing problems. REPL.BAT is pure script that will run on any Windows machine from XP onward. It performs a regular expression find/replace on stdin, and writes the result to stdout. It is very easy to use, as long as you learn regular expressions.

One tricky aspect to your problem is that leading spaces in the first column do not follow the `|` delimiter. A proper solution must handle this special case.

The following two commands will accomplish your task

```
type input.txt | repl "(^|\|) *" "$1" >input.txt.new
move /y "input.txt.new" "input.txt" >nul
```

A simple modification to the regular expression will allow it to strip both leading and trailing spaces from each column. This solution must handle the special case where trailing spaces do not precede a `|` delimiter in the last column.

```
type input.txt | repl "(^|\|) *| *($|\|)" "$1$2" >input.txt.new
move /y "input.txt.new" "input.txt" >nul
```